# Why was this VLQ answer converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

The question [What is this White Horse a reference to](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32221/46980) recently received the following answer:

> Two references actually. That's Buster Scruggs. And twin peaks.

This, to me, is a textbook very low-quality answer. The former came out in 2018, three years *after* the episode being asked about in the question; the latter is already mentioned in the question as a possibility; and neither has any kind of explanation as to why they might be the answer. It was downvoted to -5 and I would have expected it to get deleted.

Instead, a moderator converted it to a comment on the question.

Why? It clearly wasn't intended to be a comment, and it serves even less value as one than it did as an answer. I've flagged it for deletion as "no longer needed", but I'd like to try and get my head around why it was converted in the first place.

Comment: I suspect that the mod thought there might be *some* value in retaining the "information" but it clearly it does not rise to the quality of an answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that the moderator was not aware that *The Ballad of Buster Scruggs* was released three years after the episode and thought that the information in the (non) answer was worth keeping as a comment.

Comment: @galacticninja - I expect said moderator will be along shortly to explain that they have fumbly fingers.

Comment: It didn't seem like an honest attempt to answer the question. It mentioned a film released years after the episode aired and repeated *Twin Peaks* with no explanation whatsoever when the question asked if it was indeed a *Twin Peaks* reference. The answerer didn't seem to have read the question or was trolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It was a mistake

There were a number of "not an answer" flags raised by one user yesterday, all of which I rejected (with detailed explanation) except this one.  I am [not a fan of people using this flag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/how-should-moderators-respond-to-not-an-answer-flags) as an alternative to downvoting when something is just a poor answer.

However in this case, I think I just thought the answer was so short and lacking in detail it was really a comment, from someone with such low rep they can't make comments, but on reflection I should have rejected this flag too.

I've reverted this change.

#### Lesson

Flaggers: Please don't use "not an answer" flags on poor answers - even incomplete, lacking in detail or just poorly phrased answers.  This is what downvoting is for.

Reviewers:  please don't just accept such flags.

Comment: I agree, that answer should have been flagged as "very low quality" rather than "not an answer". Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the question of ***why(?)*** to the moderator that made the decision. I strongly suspect this was either a [fat-finger error](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExNTc3ZGQ4M2gxZXM1aDhvZmE2aW01OHE4eXl3Mm1ibzVrZnQ0cnBjOSZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/H1dxi6xdh4NGQCZSvz/giphy.gif) or that they simply didn't know that *'The Ballad of Buster Scruggs'* came out multiple years after *'Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt'* and thought that there was some speculative value, even if it didn't rise to the level of an actual answer.

Either way, it shouldn't have been converted into a comment. It should have just been deleted. The fact that it was on -5 should have been a clue that it was of very low value or even misleading.